# jQuery UI datepicker value doesn't get submitted

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

i have a problem with a JQuery UI datepicker. I add two datepickers to a form but when i submit the form the values of both datepickers doesn't submit. I tried with POST and GET but neither worked, not even the name of the field gets submitted. What am i missing?

Here's the code that initialize the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker_Inicio,#datepicker_Fin").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "./Images/date.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

And heres the code of the form:

```
<form class="agregarForm" action="saveClient.php" name="agregarClienteForm" method="get">
   <label class="formTitle">Agregar Cliente</label>
   <br><br>
   <label>Nombre:</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="nombre_cliente_nuevo" style="width:200px;margin-top:7px;">
   <br><br>
   <label>Duración del Contrato:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>Fecha de Inicio:</label>&nbsp;
   <input id="datepicker_Inicio" type="text"  style="width:100px;" name="fecha_inicio_contrato" onchange="dateFrom()" disabled><br>
   <input id="duracion" style="width:50px;" type="number" min="1" name="duracion_contrato" onchange="dateFrom()">&nbsp;      <label>meses</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <label>Fecha de Fin:</label>&nbsp;
   <input id="datepicker_Fin" type="text" style="width:100px;" name="fecha_fin_contrato" disabled><br><br>
   <label>Presupuesto del Contrato: $</label><br>
   <input type="text" name="presupuesto_contrato"><br><br>
   <label>Porcentaje de ingreso: </label><br>
   <label>BTW:&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="ingreso_btw"><label style="margin-right:4%;">%</label>
   <label>Herramientas:&nbsp;</label>
   <input type="text" style="width:50px;" name="inversion_herramientas"><label>%</label><br><br>
   <label>Categor&iacute;a:</label><br>
   <select id="categoriasList" name="categoria"><option>Pol&iacute;tica</option><option>IP</option></select><br><br>
   <label>Subcategor&iacute;a</label><br>
   <select id="subCat" name="subcategoria"><option id="sub1">Campa&ntilde;as</option><option id="sub2">Gobierno</option></select><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Agregar Cliente" onClick="this.form.submit()">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text fields for date are disabled. They won't get sent with the form. Remove the

```
disabled
```

part.

Comment: So without DISABLED, it still doesn't submit those fields at all? Or does it not submit the value of it only?

Comment: What does the function "this.form.submit()" do?  Within the onClick event of the button.

Comment: without DISABLED, just those fields doesnt submit. On the onclick event i do some validation (not on datepicker fields) and then submit the form, but it should submit every field. It was working alright until i change those fields from "input type=date" to a datepicker